# Not use wildcard when query solr string field value

Tags: solr

My question is I found when I use wildcard in solr query, it will be very slow. So I don't want to use the wildcard(*) query, for example, I want to search the mail address (gosling.abc@gmail.com), if I input 'abc' keywords, my q parameter maybe like q:*abc*
How should I do with this condition?

I am newbie in solr, can anyone help me?
(Currently, I have 10,937,547 document in my solr cloud. My solr version is 4.1)

Comment: Should both `g.abc` and `gabc` match this email address?
Will this email address have it's own field? Or will it be included in some bigger text chunk?

Comment: I have a field the specify the mail address, so I want to exact match mail address when use input some keywords. It didn't included in another field.